# System.IO.Exception: The handshake failed due to unexpected packed format

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, blueprism

I am trying to connect Blue Prism 6.9 Interactive client with Blue Prism 6.9 Application Server. Both components are hosted in different VM. I have enabled TLS 1.2 from registry on both VM. I have also configured SSL certificate on both VM. BP Application server says it is up and running on https and 8199 port, but when I try to connect with interactive client it throws following error:

> "Ensure that the connection mode configured on the client matches the
> connection mode configured on the server." Detailed Error:
> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
> making HTTP Request to https://ip:8199.This could be due to
> the that server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.Sys
> in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by mismatch of the
> security between the client and server.--> System.Net.WebException:
> The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error on send.-->
> System.IO.Exception: The handshake failed due to unexpected packed
> format

Any guidance would highly be appreciated.

Thank you